# Convert subnet mask to cidr notation (Scala)

Tags: scala, ip, ipv4, subnet, cidr

Here's what I have so far:

```
//converts IP to a decimal or decimal to IP (working)
private def longToIPv4(ip:Long): String = (for(a<-3 to 0 by -1) yield ((ip>>(a*8))&0xff).toString).mkString(".")
private def IPv4ToLong(ip: String): Long = ip.split("\\.").reverse.zipWithIndex.map(a => a._1.toInt * math.pow(256, a._2).toLong).sum


//convert subnet to cidr (to do)
if(ip.matches("""(\d{1,3})\.(\d{1,3})\.(\d{1,3})\.(\d{1,3})\/(\d{1,3})\.(\d{1,3})\.(\d{1,3})\.(\d{1,3})""")){
  val pattern = """(\d{1,3})\.(\d{1,3})\.(\d{1,3})\.(\d{1,3})\/(\d{1,3})\.(\d{1,3})\.(\d{1,3})\.(\d{1,3})""".r
  val pattern(o1, o2, o3, o4, o5, o6, o7, o8) = ip
}
```

I'm able to parse the subnet into octets and convert IP to decimal and vice versa, now I just need to convert `subnet` to `cidr` notation.

Comment: 255.255.248.0 -> 21

Comment: Julian, does my answer help you?

Comment: I am happy to assist! Welcome to SO! Please take the [tour] and read [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1):

According to your example in the comment, I assumed that the conversions is as elaborated [here](https://kb.wisc.edu/ns/page.php?id=3493). I wouldn't do it with regex. You can try something like:

```
def cidrToSubnet(cidr: Int): String = {
  require(cidr > 0, "CIDR is out of range! It must be between 1 (inclusive) to 32 (inclusive).")
  require(cidr < 33, "CIDR is out of range! It must be between 1 (inclusive) to 32 (inclusive).")

  val ipInInt = if (cidr == 32) (Int.MaxValue << 1) + 1 else Integer.MAX_VALUE << (32 - cidr)
  ipInInt
    .toBinaryString
    .grouped(8)
    .map(bitString => Integer.parseInt(bitString, 2))
    .mkString(".")
}

def subnetToCidr(subnet: String): Int = {
  32 - subnet.split('.')
    .map(Integer.parseInt)
    .reverse
    .zipWithIndex
    .map { 
      case (value, index) => 
        value << index * 8
    }
    .sum
    .toBinaryString
    .count(_ == '0')
}
```

Then running:

```
1.to(32).foreach(i => {
  println(i + ": cidrToSubnet(i): " + cidrToSubnet(i) + " subnetToCidr(cidrToSubnet(i): " + subnetToCidr(cidrToSubnet(i)))
})
```

outputs:

```
1: cidrToSubnet(i): 128.0.0.0 subnetToCidr(cidrToSubnet(i): 1
2: cidrToSubnet(i): 192.0.0.0 subnetToCidr(cidrToSubnet(i): 2
3: cidrToSubnet(i): 224.0.0.0 subnetToCidr(cidrToSubnet(i): 3
4: cidrToSubnet(i): 240.0.0.0 subnetToCidr(cidrToSubnet(i): 4
5: cidrToSubnet(i): 248.0.0.0 subnetToCidr(cidrToSubnet(i): 5
6: cidrToSubnet(i): 252.0.0.0 subnetToCidr(cidrToSubnet(i): 6
7: cidrToSubnet(i): 254.0.0.0 subnetToCidr(cidrToSubnet(i): 7
8: cidrToSubnet(i): 255.0.0.0 subnetToCidr(cidrToSubnet(i): 8
9: cidrToSubnet(i): 255.128.0.0 subnetToCidr(cidrToSubnet(i): 9
10: cidrToSubnet(i): 255.192.0.0 subnetToCidr(cidrToSubnet(i): 10
11: cidrToSubnet(i): 255.224.0.0 subnetToCidr(cidrToSubnet(i): 11
12: cidrToSubnet(i): 255.240.0.0 subnetToCidr(cidrToSubnet(i): 12
13: cidrToSubnet(i): 255.248.0.0 subnetToCidr(cidrToSubnet(i): 13
14: cidrToSubnet(i): 255.252.0.0 subnetToCidr(cidrToSubnet(i): 14
15: cidrToSubnet(i): 255.254.0.0 subnetToCidr(cidrToSubnet(i): 15
16: cidrToSubnet(i): 255.255.0.0 subnetToCidr(cidrToSubnet(i): 16
17: cidrToSubnet(i): 255.255.128.0 subnetToCidr(cidrToSubnet(i): 17
18: cidrToSubnet(i): 255.255.192.0 subnetToCidr(cidrToSubnet(i): 18
19: cidrToSubnet(i): 255.255.224.0 subnetToCidr(cidrToSubnet(i): 19
20: cidrToSubnet(i): 255.255.240.0 subnetToCidr(cidrToSubnet(i): 20
21: cidrToSubnet(i): 255.255.248.0 subnetToCidr(cidrToSubnet(i): 21
22: cidrToSubnet(i): 255.255.252.0 subnetToCidr(cidrToSubnet(i): 22
23: cidrToSubnet(i): 255.255.254.0 subnetToCidr(cidrToSubnet(i): 23
24: cidrToSubnet(i): 255.255.255.0 subnetToCidr(cidrToSubnet(i): 24
25: cidrToSubnet(i): 255.255.255.128 subnetToCidr(cidrToSubnet(i): 25
26: cidrToSubnet(i): 255.255.255.192 subnetToCidr(cidrToSubnet(i): 26
27: cidrToSubnet(i): 255.255.255.224 subnetToCidr(cidrToSubnet(i): 27
28: cidrToSubnet(i): 255.255.255.240 subnetToCidr(cidrToSubnet(i): 28
29: cidrToSubnet(i): 255.255.255.248 subnetToCidr(cidrToSubnet(i): 29
30: cidrToSubnet(i): 255.255.255.252 subnetToCidr(cidrToSubnet(i): 30
31: cidrToSubnet(i): 255.255.255.254 subnetToCidr(cidrToSubnet(i): 31
32: cidrToSubnet(i): 255.255.255.255 subnetToCidr(cidrToSubnet(i): 32
```

Code run at [Scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/toshetah/BCnWgymkRHyq4eBqwRyMIg/4).

Answer (score 0):

To me it looks like you want to convert something like `1.2.3.0/255.255.255.0` to `1.2.3.0/24`

With the [The IPAddress Java library](https://seancfoley.github.io/IPAddress/), it is trivial because it parses address/mask notation and can print addresses in many formats, the default format being CIDR notation.  Disclaimer: I am the project manager.

```scala
import inet.ipaddr.IPAddressString

def convert(arg: String) {
    val ipaddStr = new IPAddressString(arg)
    println(ipaddStr.getAddress)
}

convert("1.2.3.0/255.255.255.0")
```

Output:

```
1.2.3.0/24
```